# Balance files created by Spark on SPARK_LOCAL_DIR

Tags: apache-spark

I have read about the `spark.local.dir` configuration property but I still not understand how does Spark use this directory.

I have 4 machines on my cluster, there is 1 machine that plays a role as both worker and master, other machines are worker only. The `spark.local.dir` on my `spark-defaults.conf` is configured with default value `/tmp`.

Then for every Spark application, there are a lot of files created and stored on `/tmp` of machine 1 while others do not store any files/data.

How can I make the files/data created by the Spark application balanced on all machines?

Comment: all the machines where an Executor runs should have something under `SPARK_LOCAL_DIR` . Are you sure that your operation is proper parallelized and not just running on a single executor ?

Comment: yea Sanket, all applications are executed by multiple executors on different workers.